# Check two models during login with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

We are using Devise for authentication in our Rails app.  We have two models - Users and Professionals.  We have a number of Professionals who are accidentally trying to login as Users, and would like to check to see if the entered email matches a professional if it fails for a User.

For example, if the Professional tries to login as a user we would like to display a flash message like this:

"We could not find a username/password for this account, however, we did find a Professional account.  Click here to login as a Professional."

Any thoughts on how to do this with Devise?

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar with a forgotten password functionality. It could help you.

**EDIT**: added Professional check.

```
def reset
  @idiot = User.where(:email => params[:email]).first
  unless @idiot.nil?
    Notifier.send_reset_notice(@idiot).deliver
    redirect_to new_user_session_url, notice: "A new password will be emailed to #{@idiot.name}'s address shortly."
  else 
    @professional = Professional.where(:email => params[:email]).first
    unless @professional.nil?
      redirect_to new_professional_session_url, notice: "That email address is assigned to a professional. Sign in below."
    else 
      redirect_to new_user_session_url, :flash => { :error => "That email address matches no user." }
    end
  end
end
```

And in the view:

```
<%= form_tag reset_path(:email) do %>
  <%= email_field_tag :email, nil, :placeholder => 'Email address' %>
  <%= submit_tag "Reset password" %></div>
<% end %>
```

Should get you on the right track.

Comment: Thanks but your answer is just simple rails logic and has nothing to do with devise or integration into devise's session controller.